# DNN Menu XSLT to give ordinals

Tags: xslt, dotnetnuke

This is my menu template - using the DDRMenu template style

```
 <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
[*>NODE]
</ul>
[>NODE]
    <li class="[?SELECTED]active[/?]">
    [?NODE] 
        <a href="#">[=TEXT]</a>
    [?ELSE]
       <a href="[=URL]" [?TARGET]target="[=TARGET]"[/?]>[=TEXT]<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
    [/?]
    [?NODE]
        <ul class="nav nav-****second****-level">
        [*>NODE]
        </ul>
    [/?]
[/>]
```

How do I replace the ****second**** with the correct ordinal depending on how many levels down the menu goes

Answer (score 0):

I'm using below logic to show multi level menu in one project.

```
<ul>
  [*>NODE]
</ul>
[>NODE]
    <li id="languages-box-holder">
  [?ENABLED]
    <a href="[=URL]" target="[=TARGET]" class="dark-color">[=TEXT]</a>
[?ELSE]
    <span>[=TEXT]</span>
[/?]
[?NODE]
    <ul class="languages-box popup-box cream-bg">
    <li class="arrow-top"><span class="shadow cream-bg"></span></li>
    <li class="focusor-top"></li>
    [*>NODE]
    </ul>
[/?]
</li>
[/>]
```

Comment: Nice work but really I wanted to know who to turn like a '2' into the word 'second' and how to count as each level does down further

Comment: No need to count levels. CSS do by her self to render inner menus. This code do everything `<xsl:if test="node">
            <ul nid="{@id}">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node" />
            </ul>
        </xsl:if>`

Comment: @braindice I have updated my answer again as your requirement. Please check.